# funcion de click se ejecuta en dos clicks

Tags: javascript

No entiendo demasiado de `javaScript` estoy integrando una funcionalidad simple pero se ejecuta al hacer 2 `clicks` en el botón como que primero lo tiene que reconocer y luego ejecutar.

Este es el código de la función:

```
$(function () {
    // crear estado
    $(".agregar-estado").modalForm({formURL: "{% url 'complemento:agregar_estado' %}"});
    // actualizar estado   
    $(document).on('click', '.actualizar-estado', function(){
      $(this).modalForm({formURL: $(this).data('id')});
    });
    // eliminar estado
    $(document).on('click', '.eliminar-estado', function(){
      $(this).modalForm({formURL: $(this).data('id')});
    });
  });
```

El de los botones:

```html
<button  class="actualizar-estado btn btn-sm btn-primary" data-id="{% url 'complemento:editar_estado' estado.pk %}">
     <span class="fa fa-pencil"></span>
</button>

<button class="eliminar-estado btn btn-sm btn-danger" data-id="{% url 'complemento:eliminar_estado' estado.id %}">
    <span class="fa fa-trash"></span>
</button>
```

Comment: modalForm <-- que componente es? y porque lo ejecutas sobre $(this) que es el boton actual?, me suena a que tendrias que poner:
$('.actualizar-estado').modalForm(); y $('.eliminar-estado').modalForm();  justo después de crear los botones, primero les dices que son de tipo modalForm y después pueden funcionar como tales, no se si es el caso, pero algo así pasa cuando crear ejemplo un calendar combo, mientras que no lo conviertas a calendar en un inicio, funcionara como un simple input.

Comment: modalForm es una funcion que obtengo de jquery.bootstrap.modal.forms.js

Answer (score 0):

¿Por qué en vez de asignar la función al boton `$(document)` la asignas al documento y después le dices el elemento? `$('#idDelElemento')`

Trata de esta forma:

```js
$(function () {
    // crear estado
    $(".agregar-estado").modalForm({formURL: "{% url 'complemento:agregar_estado' %}"});
    // actualizar estado   
    $("#btn-actualizar").on('click', function(){
      $(this).modalForm({formURL: $(this).data('id')});
    });
    // eliminar estado
    $("#btn-eliminar").on('click', function(){
      $(this).modalForm({formURL: $(this).data('id')});
    });
  });
```

Y para el HTML:

```html
<button id="btn-actualizar" class="actualizar-estado btn btn-sm btn-primary" data-id="{% url 'complemento:editar_estado' estado.pk %}">
     <span class="fa fa-pencil"></span>
</button>

<button id="btn-eliminar"class="eliminar-estado btn btn-sm btn-danger" data-id="{% url 'complemento:eliminar_estado' estado.id %}">
    <span class="fa fa-trash"></span>
</button>
```

Si aún no entiendes bien JavaScript deberías aprender Vanilla antes de entrar a usar JQuery desde mi punto de vista.

Comment: claro esa era la primera opción pero al cambiar de lista en el data table no reconoce las funciones

Comment: Entonces en los botones añade el onclick="nombreFuncion()" entre los parentesis puedes enviar el boton colocando this y se envia con todos y sus "data-" ya podrías acceder a ellas con this.getAttribute() e incluso reasignar valores a ese mismo elemento

Comment: si entiendo que es simple lo que tratas de decir pero no llevo mucho tiempo viendo javaScript asi que en lo del getAttribute no sabria como obtener los valores y menos adaptarlo a lo que estaba haciendo

Comment: Te recomiendo la web de mozilla https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript para aprender y para buscar dudas que tengas, igual en google, aunque parezcan dudas muy específicas siempre hay alguien que ya pregunto algo similar y puede ayudar

Comment: despues de ver unos temas basicos de vanilla probe la forma que me comentaste que la llegue a comprender y aun asi no lo reconoce a la primera solo a la 2da tambien hice la prueba de que ingresara a la funcion y se ejecuta 2 veces cuando coloco un comentario tienes alguna otra sugerencia para el problema ?